# ReactJS Testing - Check if component did render after async call in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Sometimes my react application crashes on some pages, after I changed the API. Now I want to add tests to the application that check, if the components (re)render without crashing after an API call has been made (all calls are made inside the `componentDidMount()` function).

Currently my test is really simple and looks like this:

```
it(route.path + ' renders without crashing', async () => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        const Component = route.component;

        ReactDOM.render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Component />
            </Provider>
            , div);
    });
```

But this only checks, if the application renders, before the API call returned something.
How can I add something like an `await`, to check if the data from `componentDidMount`loaded?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I checked out RTL - but I'm still having trouble. It always says that it can't find the element. Here is my code:

```
import { render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

test('examples of some things', async () => {

    const { getByTestId, findByTestId } = render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Page />
        </Provider>
    );

    await waitFor(() =>
        expect(getByTestId("table")).toBeInTheDocument()
    );
})
```

**EDIT 2**

The `<Page />` component renders a `<AnotherComponent />`, Inside this component, an Ajax call is made to load some data, which then should be rendered:

```
export default class Page {

    render(
        ...
        ...
        <AnotherComponent />
    );
}

export default class AnotherComponent {
     componentDidMount() {
         someApiCall().then(set State...);
     }

     render(
        ....
        ...
        {
            this.state.someAPIdata &&
               <div data-testid="table">
                   ...
                   ...
               </div>
        }
     );
}
```

When I run the test, the tests already returns an error, even before the API call finished

Comment: In RTL there's waitFor specifically for such cases.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for your answer. I tried it, but I'm still having trouble to get the test running. Can you help me?

Comment: It's unknown why it fails the expectation because you didn't provide the component you're testing. FWIW `getByTestId("table")` presumes there's `data-testid="table"` attribute in the output, see the docs. If you didn't expect it to behave like that, that's why it fails.